# request and session attribute value returns null in @ModelAttribute method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, modelattribute

Am using spring mvc  i want to access an request attribute inside `@ModelAttribute` method but its giving only null

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "data")
    public ModelAndView aaaa()
             {
        String courseId = httpServletRequest.getParameter("courseValue");
        System.out.println("course value data :" + courseId); // here am getting value

        httpServletRequest.setAttribute("courseId", courseId); // setting in request 
         attribute
        WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(httpServletRequest, "courseId", courseId);
        // setting in   session attribute
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("abc");
        return modelAndView;
    }



   @ModelAttribute("termList")
   public Map<String, String> def(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) 
    {
    String courseId = (String) WebUtils
            .getSessionAttribute(httpServletRequest, "courseId");
    System.out.println("course value in term :" + courseId); // here its giving null
    Map<String, String>map = courseSubLinkService.getTermDetailsBasedOnCourseId
            (courseId);

    httpServletRequest.setAttribute("termList", map);
    return map;

   }
```

I dont know where i did wrong please help me to get this value

Comment: please clarify you question. which line is giving null?

Comment: System.out.println("course value in term :" + courseId); printing null

Answer (score 0):

From Spring docs:

> @ModelAttribute methods in a controller are invoked before
>   @RequestMapping methods, within the same controller

This means that in moment when `def` is invoked HttpServletRequest hasn't attribute that you need because you set this attribute in `aaaa` method that will be invoked after `def`.

Comment: Is there any way to pass value to model attribute